# Logging full stack trace performance issue

Tags: java, logging, apache-commons

I was investigating the code for ExceptionUtils getFullStackTrace in Apache commons library and it is as follows:

```
public static String getFullStackTrace(Throwable throwable) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw, true);
            Throwable[] ts = getThrowables(throwable);
            for (int i = 0; i < ts.length; i++) {
                ts[i].printStackTrace(pw);
                if (isNestedThrowable(ts[i])) {
                    break;
                }
           }
            return sw.getBuffer().toString();
        }
```

And I noticed that it doesn't close the PrintWriter and makes auto flush only.

Will not closing the PrintWriter results in  a memory leak?

I am logging into a file with FileWriter,with all the exceptions that happens and I want to use the above method to log the full stack trace.

But then I replaced it with the following because i suspected that it can create a memory leak:

```
public static String stackTraceToString(Throwable e) throws Exception {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw,true);
        e.printStackTrace(pw);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(sw.toString());
        sw.flush();
        sw.close();
        pw.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

What do you think of the performance for CPU and memory for the two methods, which one will perform better ?

**EDIT: Custom Logger Code**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;


public class AppLogger
{
    public static String MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR = "ERROR";
    public static String MESSAGE_TYPE_INFO = "INFO";
    public static boolean DISABLE_LOG = false;

    private static final String _logFilePath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getInitParameter("LogFilePath");
    private static FileWriter _fw;
    private AppLogger() 
    {
    }


    public static String stackTraceToString(Throwable e) throws Exception {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw,true);
        e.printStackTrace(pw);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(sw.toString());
        sw.flush();
        sw.close();
        pw.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }



    public static void Log(Exception e)
    {
        if(DISABLE_LOG)
            return;
        try
        {             
            _fw = new FileWriter(_logFilePath + getFileName(), true);
            _fw.write(formatMessage(stackTraceToString(e), AppLogger.MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR,null));
            _fw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            releaseResources(); 
        }
    }

    private static void releaseResources()
    {
        if(_fw != null)
        {
            try
            {
                _fw.close();
                _fw = null;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
               e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        }
    }


    private static String getFileName()
    {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("logFile.").append(sdf.format(gc.getTime())).append(".log");  
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String formatMessage(String message, String messageType,String className)
    {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if(className != null)
          sb.append(sdf.format(gc.getTime())).append(" ").append(messageType).append(" ").append(className).append(" : ").append(message).append("\n");
        else
          sb.append(sdf.format(gc.getTime())).append(" ").append(messageType).append(" ").append(" : ").append(message).append("\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you create a StringBuilder, and append only one String to it? Why not just return that String?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it will not. Here is the code for `PrintWriter.close` - as you can see, all it does is close the Writer it wraps (`out`), with some additional synchronization and "error handling":

```
public void close() {
    try {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (out == null)
                return;
            out.close();
            out = null;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
}
```

In this case, it closes the StringWriter. Here is the code for `StringWriter.close`:

```
/**
 * Closing a <tt>StringWriter</tt> has no effect. The methods in this
 * class can be called after the stream has been closed without generating
 * an <tt>IOException</tt>.
 */
public void close() throws IOException {
}
```

As you can see, it does exactly nothing - and this is specified in the documentation, not merely an implementation detail.

Closing streams is important for things like files (in which case it stops preventing other processes from writing to the file), network connections (in which case it disconnects), and several other types of streams and Writers; however, it is not important for `StringWriter` (and the stream equivalent `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and the input equivalents `StringReader` and `ByteArrayInputStream`).

Comment: thanks for your explanation, i edited the post will you please look at my custom logger code and tell if it can be optimized for cpu and memory more than that.

Comment: @MahmoudS - Do you have any evidence that it >>needs<< to be optimized?  Try Googling for "premature optimization" ..................

Comment: yes some times my application memory grows largely and i have a suspect that it maybe because of this custom logger but from your responses it seems not, thanks for clearing it out

Comment: @MahmoudS use a memory analyzer then, don't just guess without evidence.

Comment: Do you have **hard evidence** that **this code** needs to be optimized?  If you optimize (or look for memory leaks) based purely on suspicion, you are going to waste a lot of your time fixing the wrong problem.

Comment: ... and also "fixing" things which are not problems.

Answer (score 1):

> will not closing the PrintWriter makes a memory issue ?

Short answer: No.

Longer answer:

The reason it is advisable to close readers, writers, input and output streams ... and similar things like sockets ... is that these objects are wrappers for limited resources that are managed by the operating system.  If the application doesn't close them explicitly or using try-with-resource then there is a risk that the resource (pool) will run out.  That can lead to the OS refusing to open files, sockets, database connections etcetera.

But for `StringWriter` and similar, there is no such OS resource.  The object is merely capturing data in an in-heap buffer.  That buffer will be recycled by the garbage collector ... assuming that it is no longer referenced.  Closing it doesn't make any difference.

(And @immibis's exposition of the code confirms this ...)

---

> But then I replaced it with the following because i suspected that it can create a memory leak

It won't.  However ...

> What do you think of the performance for CPU and memory for the two methods, which one will perform better ?

The extra time taken for the slower version is likely to be so small that it makes no practical difference.  (But if you really, really want to know ... bench mark it.)

Comment: thanks for your good explanation, i added my custom logger code also.